# Como conectar varios servidores a un cliente?

Tags: java, socket

tengo que hacer un programa, el cual el cliente sea el que gestione varios servidores mediante sockets. Solo he encontrado información en este sitio web como en otros de hacerlo al contrario, es decir, de conectar varios clientes a un servidor, lo que necesito es conectar varios servidores a un solo cliente.
Es esto posible?
Gracias.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Estoy haciendo esto de la siguiente manera:
El cliente gestiona a los servidores conectados, el cliente envía un numero para que los servidores conectados calculen cuantos números primos hay desde 0 hasta ese numero ingresado por el cliente, los servidores calculan esto y envían el tiempo de ejecución al cliente, luego el cliente gestiona el resto de cosas, que aun no he he hecho porque no se si lo que llevo, con respecto a las conexiones del cliente y el servidor este bien.

```
public class Client extends Thread {

    protected ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    private int port;
    private String name;
    private int n;
    private long tiempo;
    private Main main;
    private int id;

    public Client(int id, int port, String name, int n, Main main) {
        this.id = id;
        this.port = port;
        this.name = name;
        this.n = n;
        this.main = main;
    }

    //Private class
    class ClientSocket implements Runnable {

        private Socket socket;

        protected ClientSocket(Socket sock) {
            socket = sock;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            DataOutputStream out = null;
            DataInputStream in = null;
            try {
                in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                //MANDAMOS EL NUMERO EN RANGO HACIA LOS SERVIDORES
                out.writeInt(n);
                out.flush();
                //LEEMOS EL TIEMPO ENVIADO POR EL SERVIDOR
                tiempo = in.readLong();
                System.out.println(tiempo);
                //MANDAMOS EL ID DEL PROCESO

                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                Computer c = (Computer) ois.readObject();
                synchronized (main) {
                    main.add(c);
                }
                ois.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } finally {
                try {
                    out.close();
                    in.close();
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        startClient();
        super.run();
    }

    private void startClient() {
        ServerSocket ss = null;
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            ss = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Esperando Conexion");

            do {
                socket = ss.accept();

                threadPool.execute(new ClientSocket(socket));

            } while (true);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                socket.close();
                ss.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SERVIDOR**

```
public class Server implements Runnable {

    private Thread thread;
    private String nameThread;
    private int port;
    private String ip;
    private long tiempo;
    private Main main;
    private int id;

    public Server(int id, Main main, String nameThread, int port, String ip) {
        this.nameThread = nameThread;
        this.port = port;
        this.ip = ip;
        this.main = main;
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.startServer();
    }

    public void start() {
        if (this.thread == null) {
            this.thread = new Thread(this, nameThread);
            this.thread.start();
        }
    }

    private synchronized void startServer() {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket(ip, port);
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            int n = in.readInt();
            long time = encontrarPrimos(n);
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            out.writeLong(time);
            out.flush();

            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            Computer c = new Computer(id, ip, time, System.getenv("USERDOMAIN"));
            oos.writeObject(c);

            oos.close();
            in.close();
            out.close();
            socket.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public void join() {
        try {
            this.thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public long getTiempo() {
        return tiempo;
    }

    private long encontrarPrimos(int n) {
        long inicio = System.nanoTime();
        int cant = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            if (evaluarNumero(i)) {
                cant++;
            }
        }
        //System.out.println("Cantidad de numeros: " + cant);
        long fin = System.nanoTime();
        long finalTime = fin - inicio;
        //System.out.println("Tiempo: " + finalTime);
        return finalTime;
    }

    private boolean evaluarNumero(int numero) {
        boolean primo = false;
        int contador = 0;
        for (int i = numero; i > 0; i--) {
            if (numero % i == 0) {
                contador++;
            }
        }
        if (contador == 2) {
            primo = true;
        }
        return primo;
    }
}
```

**MAIN CLIENTE**

```
public class Main {
    private ArrayList<Computer> servers = new ArrayList<>();

    public Main() {
        System.out.println("Ingrese dato...");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        Client c = new Client(0, 5000, "Cliente", n, this);
        c.start();
        Collections.sort(servers, new Sortbytime());
        this.servers.forEach((server) -> {
            System.out.println(server.toString());
        });
    }


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
    }

    public int getSizeServers(){
        return this.servers.size();
    }

    public void add(Computer c){
        this.servers.add(c);
    }

}
```

Comment: Sí se puede. Estoy suponiendo que el cliente tendría una aplicación java. ¿correcto?

Comment: @AlbertoLopez Exacto, tanto el cliente tiene la aplicación java, y este de sebe conectar a múltiples servidores, el problema es que no se como hacerlo, se hacerlo al contrario, de un servidor a varios clientes.

Comment: La aplicación cliente puede usar java.net.ServerSocket, y escuchar un puerto y por ende recibir solicitudes de conexión (sockets), y las aplicaciones de los servidores solo tendrían que conectarse al cliente a su url para obtener un socket. Y así podrían comunicarse.

Comment: He hecho la aplicacion para el servidor y para el cliente correspondiente, actualizare la pregunta para colocar el codigo

Comment: @AlbertoLopez Listo, ya actualice la pregunta con el codigo, tanto para el servidor como para el cliente.

Comment: no entiendo. Tu clase Client está haciendo la función de un servidor, y tu clase Server está haciendo las funciones de un cliente.

Comment: @AlbertoLopez Mas o menos lo hice así, ya que el cliente debe conectarse a varios servidores.

Comment: Ese sería el esquema que yo usaría. Solo cambiaría el nombre de las clases por Gestionador y Gestionado, u otros nombres, para evitar confusiones.

Comment: @AlbertoLopez Ok bro, gracias, ahora tengo otro problema, porque necesito que se ejecute código en el main, pero al entrar al ciclo infinito del cliente, este no se ejecuta, no se por que, aun ejecutando el socket del cliente en un hilo aparte del main

Comment: no estás poniendo el método main

Comment: @AlbertoLopez Ya actualice la pregunta con el codigo del main del cliente.

Comment: Si puedo ejecutar el ciclo. Puedes poner como lanzas los Servers?